# Solving $\frac{dy}{dt}+y=1$ differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

When solving $\frac{dy}{dt} +y = 1$, I get the answer $y= 1-Ae^t$, however the answer claims to be $y= 1-Ae^{-t}$

Where does this minus come from?

Comment: If you use the general approach with characteristic polynomial, then the characteristic polynomial of homogeneous is $k+1=0 \Rightarrow k=-1$, so the solution of homogeneous is $C*e^{-t}$. The solution of inhomogeneous is $C(t)e^{-t}$, so $$(C(t)*e^{-t})' + C(t)e^{-t} = 1 \Rightarrow C'(t)e^{-t} = 1,$$ so $C'(t) = e^t$ and $C(t) = e^t + A$. Thus $$C(t)e^{-t}=1+Ae^{-t}. $$

Comment: Where does your plus comes from ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

When you integrate after taking the same terms on same side you get $\frac {\log (1-y)} {-1} = t+c$ where $c$ is the constant of integration. This $-1$ here gives the minus sign after solving.

Comment: @Alex M. Thank you for the edit

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact method you use to approach the problem. If you use the method of integrating factors, the integrating factor is $e^{\int 1 dt}=e^t$, so $\frac{d}{dt}(e^t y)=e^t$, so $e^t y = e^t + A$, so $y=1+Ae^{-t}$. (Since $A$ is an arbitrary constant, the $+$ can be a $-$.)

Other methods would be separation of variables and linear superposition (homogeneous solution+particular solution = general solution).

Answer (score 1):

You can verify your solution by plugging it into the equation.

$$(1-Ae^t)'+(1-Ae^t)=-Ae^t+1-Ae^t\color{red}{\ne1}.$$

You clearly see that this solution is wrong, but the fix isn't far, it suffices to change one sign...

Answer (score 0):

$$y'(t)+y(t)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(t)=1-y(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(t)}{1-y(t)}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(t)}{1-y(t)}\space\text{d}t=\int1\space\text{d}t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(t)}{1-y(t)}\space\text{d}t=t+\text{C}$$

---

For the integral substitute $u=1-y(t)$ and $\text{d}u=-y'(t)\space\text{d}t$:

$$\int\frac{y'(t)}{1-y(t)}\space\text{d}t=-\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}t=-\ln\left|u\right|+\text{C}=-\ln\left|1-y(t)\right|+\text{C}$$

---

So, we get:

$$-\ln\left|1-y(t)\right|=t+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln\left|1-y(t)\right|=\text{C}-t\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|1-y(t)\right|=\exp\left[\text{C}-t\right]\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|1-y(t)\right|=\frac{\text{C}}{e^t}$$